# remove latin-1 character from large text file in bash

Tags: utf-8, dataset, iso-8859-1

I have some large dataset plain text files (wikipedia articles) and I have to remove latin-1 characters like here:

```
 kemer } şehir kır toplam }}
use specific terminology . for example , it is often more appropriate for people or things from ethiopia ( a country in africa ) to be described as ethiopian , not carelessly ( with the risk of stereotyping ) as african . 
 bat avg . 
 label ਕਾਲਜ
 ਅਡੋਲਫ ਹਿਟਲਰ ਨੇ ਦੇਸ਼ ਵਿਚ ਕਮਿਊਨਿਸਟ ਪਾਰਟੀ ਬਣਾਉਣ ਦੀ ਇਜਾਜ਼ਤ ਦੇਣ ਤੋਂ ਨਾਂਹ ਕਰ ਦਿਤੀ।
 alt }
        if not extra_units then
 utc_offset + 
 ਕਬਜਾ ( ) 
 demographics _title regional
```

I want to get only like

```
ਕਾਲਜ
 ਅਡੋਲਫ ਹਿਟਲਰ ਨੇ ਦੇਸ਼ ਵਿਚ ਕਮਿਊਨਿਸਟ ਪਾਰਟੀ ਬਣਾਉਣ ਦੀ ਇਜਾਜ਼ਤ ਦੇਣ ਤੋਂ ਨਾਂਹ ਕਰ ਦਿਤੀ।

 ਕਬਜਾ
```

and eventually trim white space lines that is trivial.
The approach I have used was the following

```
<?php
$in = fopen('php://stdin','rb');
while($line = stream_get_line($in, 64000)) {
    foreach(str_split($line) as $char) {
        $ordChar = ord($char);
        if($ordChar > 127 || $ordChar <= 31) {
            echo $char;
        }
    }
}
```

used like `cat wiki.hi.txt | php -d memory_limit=1024M escape_latin.php > wiki.hi.esc.txt`

This approach works ok, the only issue is that performances are getting worst as the file size grows as I can see with a `watch du -h filename` on the file I'm working on with. I'm surprised because I'm working on a local disk and I'm using `stream_get_line` to get the lines in streaming.

I have tried the same approach in python, but I get pretty the same performances with file size of ~1GB.

see [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/647) for more details.

**[UPDATE]**
I'm reporting here some results from alternative approaches proposed

Using the `regex` approach, that seems to produce pretty much the same output file:

A **~50MB** file

```
$ time tr -d "[:alnum:][:punct:]" < wiki.as.txt > wiki.as.test.txt

real    0m2.990s
user    0m2.818s
sys 0m0.088s
```

A **~100MB** file

```
$ time tr -d "[:alnum:][:punct:]" < wiki.gu.txt > wiki.gu.test.txt

real    0m7.322s
user    0m6.772s
sys 0m0.282s
```

A **~600MB** file

```
$ time tr -d "[:alnum:][:punct:]" < wiki.ta.txt > wiki.ta.test.txt

real    0m35.973s
user    0m33.498s
sys 0m1.254s
```

A **~1000MB (1GB)** file

```
$ time tr -d "[:alnum:][:punct:]" < wiki.ja.1.txt > wiki.ja.1.test.txt

real    1m5.409s
user    1m0.669s
sys 0m2.068s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a regex.

If you're running it from a CLI, try something like

```
tr -d "[:alnum:][:punct:]" < wiki.hi.txt > wiki.hi.esc.txt
```

If you prefer to do the same in php -

```
<?php
$in = fopen('php://stdin','rb');
while($line = stream_get_line($in, 64000)) {
    echo preg_replace('/[:alnum:][:punct:]/', '', $line);        
}
```

But *please* check these to make sure they are doing what you want - esp. the php, since I'm working without a test setup here. It's likely to have syntax issues and/or worse. With luck someone will edit it or offer a better solution, or at least comment and point out whatever I may have done wrong.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying the simplest regex approach. The result file seems to be ok. For the performances on different file sizes, I have updated the question above. It seems to be very promising.

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped. Accept the solution?